# SWT GridLayout automatic column count

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm using a SWT GridLayout for displaying different images in, such a wonder - a Grid.
Now my problem is, that the GridLayout has always a fixed column count, lets say 5. 
Is there any way to make the GridLayout flexible, so that the column count increase or decrease depending on the size of the parent component? (E.g. when the window is resizied).

I could not find an option in the GridLayoutConstructor or the GridData. A RowLayout does not fill my needs

Comment: Can you not use `setColumns()` ans `setRows()` in the resize listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the layout at runtime.

When your parent component's size changes, change its `GridLayout`'s `numColumns` property and call `layout(true)` on the parent component.

```
final Shell shell = new Shell();

final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout( 3, true );
shell.setLayout( layout );

shell.addControlListener( new ControlAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void controlResized( ControlEvent event ) {
        int newColumnNumber = 5; // Calculate your new value here.
        layout.numColumns = newColumnNumber;
        shell.layout( true );
    }
} );
```

Comment: I'll try it and let you know if it helped

Comment: This was not the exact solution for my problem, but it helped me a lot to get in the right direction - thanks